# Use fullPage.js plugin on a non-fullscreen element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I have an element on my page that extends from 100px from the top of the page, to 200px from the bottom. It is 100% of the width of the page.

I want to have content inside of here in the form of slides, so that they can be slid through using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). The problem is that this element doesn't take up the whole page, whereas fullPage.js requires the element to take up the whole page.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can always overide the inline styles by doing something like this:

```
.section{
   height: auto !important;
}
```

You can try to use the class `fp-auto-height` [provided by fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections) and use it in your section:

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height">
```

This way these styles will be applied to the section:

```
.fp-auto-height.fp-section,
.fp-auto-height .fp-slide,
.fp-auto-height .fp-tableCell{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

The purpose of the class is usually to deal with sections smaller than the viewport, such as footers. But you can also use it for bigger sections if you want to.